# What has to be an input shape for a CNN using MFCC?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, mfcc

I am doing some classification on audio data using MFCC. I have extracted MFCCs from a few audio samples and I would like to pass them to a CNN, however I have hard time understanding what `input_shape` parameter I should provide to my model for training and classifications.

The training set `train_x` has the following shape: `(213, 1723, 39)`. Hence 213 samples, each of those are 1723 by 39.

That's how my model looks like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,[2,2],data_format='channels_last',activation='sigmoid',input_shape=(?, ?)))
model.add(Conv2D(128,[2,2],data_format='channels_last',activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Flatten(data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64,activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(32,activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(4,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data=(test_x, test_y), epochs=2, batch_size=16)
```

What should be the input shape for the first layer? What does it make with the batch size? What are general rules for understanding how to define an input shape?